# Let $G=\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus \mathbb{N}}$. Prove that $G \times G \cong G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus \mathbb{N}}$. Prove that $G \times G \cong G$
This is an exercise in free group.My approach:
$G\cong F^{ab}(\mathbb{N}), G\times G \cong F^{ab}(\mathbb{N}) \times F^{ab}(\mathbb{N})$.Then to prove $F^{ab}(\mathbb{N}) \cong F^{ab}(\mathbb{N}) \times F^{ab}(\mathbb{N})$.Then what to do next? I konw that $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} ... \mathbb{Z}$(n times) $\cong F^{ab}(${$x_1,...,x_n$}$)$,can it be used in this exercise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements of $\mathbb Z^{\oplus\mathbb N}$ are maps $f\colon \mathbb N\to \mathbb Z$ of finite support, that is, only finitely many elements of $\mathbb N$ have non-zero images $f(k)\neq 0$. The addition of $f,g\in\mathbb Z^{\oplus \mathbb N}$ is defined by $(f+g)(n) := f(n)+g(n)$, which still has finite support.

The elements of $\mathbb Z^{\oplus\mathbb N}\times \mathbb Z^{\oplus\mathbb N}$ are pairs of maps $f_1,f_2\colon \mathbb N\to\mathbb Z$, each of finite support. These pairs correspond to finitely supported maps $\mathbb N\sqcup \mathbb N\to \mathbb Z$, where $\mathbb N\sqcup \mathbb N := (\mathbb N \times \{1\}) \cup (\mathbb N \times \{2\})$ is the disjoint union of two copies of $\mathbb N$.

This gives an isomorphism
\begin{align*}
\Psi\colon \mathbb Z^{\oplus\mathbb N} \times \mathbb Z^{\oplus\mathbb N} &\longrightarrow \mathbb Z^{\oplus(\mathbb N \sqcup \mathbb N)}, \\
(f_1,f_2) &\longmapsto \left.\Big( (k,i) \mapsto f_i(k) \right).
\end{align*}

Now given any set bijection $\varphi\colon X\to Y$ you get an isomorphism
\begin{align*}
\varphi^* \colon \mathbb Z^{\oplus Y} &\longrightarrow \mathbb Z^{\oplus X},\\
f &\longmapsto f\circ \varphi.
\end{align*}

Now take $\varphi$ to be any bijection $\mathbb N \to \mathbb N \sqcup \mathbb N$ to obtain isomorphisms
$$
\mathbb Z^{\oplus\mathbb N} \times \mathbb Z^{\oplus\mathbb N} \xrightarrow{\Psi} \mathbb Z^{\oplus(\mathbb N \sqcup \mathbb N)}
\xrightarrow{\Phi^*} \mathbb Z^{\oplus\mathbb N}.
$$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Consider $\varphi:G\to G\times G$
$$(a_n)\mapsto ((a_{2n}),\,(a_{2n-1}))\,.$$

Comment: can you give more details? what does $a_n$ means?Thanks!

Comment: $(a_n)$ is an element of $G=\Bbb Z^{\oplus \Bbb N}$, i.e. a sequence of integer numbers such that $a_k=0$ for $k>N$ for some $N\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: Why $a_n$ is 'an' element, i think it contains infinite mapps ,for example,$a_1$ contains all the mapps such that send all integer number k  that  $k>1$ to 0,but 1 can be sent to any integer numbers.I means that does $a_n$ represent all the mapps $\phi$ that  $\phi(k)=0$ for all $k>n$,$\phi(k)$ is any integer numer for all $k\leq n?$

Comment: Sorry, $(a_n)$ denotes here a particular sequence $(a_0,a_1,a_2, a_3, \dots)$ that is, a function $a:\Bbb N\to \Bbb Z$ if you prefer. Without parenthesis, $a_n$ denotes the $n$th element of the sequence, which is $a(n)$ if you consider the sequence as a function from $\Bbb N$. Besides the notation, did you get the answer?

Comment: I have got the answer from Christoph.I am interesting in your answer ,but sorry that I am still confused

Comment: My answer is basically the same, but with different notation and with a specific bijection $\varphi:\Bbb N\to \Bbb N\sqcup \Bbb N$ namely cutting $\Bbb N$ to odd and even numbers ($\varphi(2n)=(n,1)$ and $\varphi(2n-1)=(n,2)$).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an "abstract nonsense" answer: The free abelian group functor is the left adjoint of the forgetful functor from the category of abelian groups to the category of sets. Thus it preserves colimits. In particular, $F^{ab}(S_1)\oplus F^{ab}(S_2)\cong F^{ab}(S_1\sqcup S_2)$. Of course, for finitely many factors the direct product and direct sum of groups coincide. To finish your proof, you have to show that $\mathbb{N}\sqcup \mathbb{N}$ is equipotent to $\mathbb{N}$, which is elementary set theory.

Remark: This answer is mainly to provide some perspective. For many it will feel needlessly abstract, in which case I suggest writing down the isomorphism explicitly following the hint from Berci's answer.

Comment: This was probably useless to the OP but entertaining for me, so thanks!

Comment: Not necessarily useless for the OP, as it's following the initial track, using free Abelian groups.